# Java sort array list to find highest Integer

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, compare

I have an array list of Player Objects. These players all have high scores. I'm not sure how to go through the arraylist and find the player with the highest score. The Collections.sort does not work for this

```
public void determineWinner() {

        for (int i = 0; i < playersList.size(); i++) {
             playersList.get(i).getFrameScores2();
             System.out.println("**************");
             System.out.println("Player " + playersList.get(i).getName() + " total score is : " + playersList.get(i).getTotalScore());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Implement any one out of Comparator/Comparable interface to sort the array and then simply access the last index to get the highest score

Comment: sorting is extra effort, why not just iterating through your list, keep the previous highest scoring player and compare the current player with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with an appropriate [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Player topScorer = Collections.max(playerList, new Comparator<Player>() {
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return Integer.compare(p1.getTotalScore(), p2.getTotalScore());
    }
});
```

If the `Player` objects naturally sort themselves using the `getTotalScore()` attribute, consider making `Player` implement `Comparable<Player>`, using code similar to the above. Then to find the highest scorer, you would just call `Collections.max(playerList);` (without having to provide a `Comparator`).

Comment: Thank you, really efficient. Solved